# Paperclip not Uploading to Bucket, No Error Returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have been battling this one for a while now. I have am using Paperclip and AWS-SDK. I have my bucket and account configured. Permissions are granted. The form data, including the Paperclip model values all save to my Sqlite3 table. However, the image does not upload to my bucket on S3. I receive no errors. Any suggestions on what could be going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Here's is the attachment control, which is inside my form. The form routes to the Create method on my Animal controller.

#### Development Config (I have verified I am in dev mode)

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"

 config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => ENV["my bucket"],
  :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV["My ID"],
      :secret_access_key => ["My Secret"]
  }
}

  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] =    '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

#### Animal/new.html.erb

```
   <div class="form-group padding-top-bottom-10">
      <%= f.file_field :animal_image %>
      <label class="label label-warning">Attach Your Photo</label>
      <div class="row padding-top-bottom-10"></div>
   </div>
```

#### Animal Controller

```
 def create

@animal = Animal.new(animal_params)
respond_to do |format|
    if @animal.save
      flash[:notice] = "#{@animal.full_name} has been added to your profile."
      format.json { render json: @animal, status: :created, location: @animal }
      format.html { render "animal/index" }
    else
      flash.now[:error] = @animal.errors.full_messages
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @animal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
def animal_params

params.require(:animal).permit(:full_name, :profile_id, :age, :gender, :purr_factor,           :weight, :height,
                                            :length, :fixed, :shots, :papers, :animal_desc, :breed_id, :animal_image)
end
```

#### Animal.rb

```
        :animal_image_content_type
        :animal_image_file_name

        has_attached_file :animal_image, style: {
         thumb: '100x100>',
         square: '200x200#',
         medium: '300x300>'
        }

        # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
       validates_attachment_content_type :animal_image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Comment: Really a -1 for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out and I figured I should post the solution, so that way I can get more down votes. Even though I have seen countless Paperclip posts on here with similar problems, whom, received multiple up votes.

Removing the credentials from my config/environments/development file and placing all configuration in my model seemed to do the trick. Also, I had a hash symbol in my style field.

```
  has_attached_file :animal_image,
                    :style => {:medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>"},
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :bucket  => "my bucket",
                    :s3_credentials => {
                        :bucket  => "my bucket",
                        :access_key_id => ENV["My key"],
                        :secret_access_key => ENV["My Secret"]
                    },
                    :s3_permissions => "private",
                    :url => ":s3_domain_url"
                    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ":s3_domain_url"
                    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
```